# error this.getNaticeComponent is not a function (it is undefined) in react native maps

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-maps

hello i have this issue

i have the error error this.getNaticeComponent is not a function (it is undefined)

i follow the step in this issue to trie to fix it https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/issues/4467

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Image, View, TouchableOpacity, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import MapView, { Circle, Marker } from 'react-native-maps';

import { WIDTH } from '../../constants'; 
interface Props {
  mapStyle?: any;
  latitude: any;
  longitude: any;
  latitudeDelta?: any;
  longitudeDelta?: any;
  children?: any;
}

const MapViewCustom = ({ mapStyle, latitude, longitude, latitudeDelta, longitudeDelta, children }: Props) => {
return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <MapView style={[styles.map, mapStyle]}

            scrollEnabled={false}
            region={{
                latitude: latitude,
                longitude: longitude,
                latitudeDelta: latitudeDelta || 0.02,
                longitudeDelta: longitudeDelta || 0.02,
            }}>
            <Marker
                coordinate={{ latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude }}

            />
        </MapView>
    </View>
);
}

export default MapViewCustom;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

map: {
    height: 200,
    marginVertical: 10,
    borderRadius: 5,
    borderWidth: 1,
    width: WIDTH * 0.85

   }
})
```

i use "react-native-maps": "^1.7.1", "react-native": "0.72.5",

and there is my babel.config.js

```
require('./config/env/loadEnv');
```

module.exports = function (api) {
api.cache(true);

return {

```
presets: [
  ['@babel/preset-env', { targets: { node: 'current' } }],
  '@babel/preset-react',
  'module:metro-react-native-babel-preset',
  "@babel/preset-typescript",
],
plugins: [
  ["@babel/plugin-transform-class-properties", { "loose": true }],
  ["@babel/plugin-transform-private-methods", { "loose": true }],
  ['react-native-reanimated/plugin'],
  ["@babel/plugin-transform-private-property-in-object", { "loose": true }],
  [
    'module:react-native-dotenv',
    {
      envName: 'MY_ENV',
      moduleName: '@env',
      blacklist: null,
      whitelist: null,
      safe: false,
      allowUndefined: true,
    },
  ],
],
```

};
};